# Invoking Facebook app on iOS to a specific Facebook page

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, invoke

I would like to know if it is possible to invoke the Facebook app and connect to my Facebook app page. I was thinking of creating a 'Like us on Facebook' button from within the app so that once the Facebook app is invoked, it is already on my app Facebook page for users to like.

How can one achieve this?

Let's say for the sake of argument, my Facebook app page is [www.facebook.com/supercoolapp](http://www.facebook.com/supercoolapp)

Is there some sort of method I can implement to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link `fb://profile/135057709986569` would open my Facebook page on iOS if the Facebook app is installed. Just replace the number with your Facebook ID. (Find it by going to your page admin menu and looking at the url).

Next you can open it via code like this:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/135057709986569"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18

This wiki shows you a huge list of possible facebook app links: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for!